# All I need to know about FRTB

Tags: risk, banking-regulations, market-risk, frtb

I know the basics of FRTB (Fundamental Review of the Trading Book) but I can see that most of the risk management books have maximum a chapter dedicated to FRTB and are relatively old so don't reflect the latest requirements.

What is the best up-to-date source I can use to have a clear coverage of all the aspects related to FRTB?

Ideally I would like to see some example of how the calculations are performed when portfolios include various instruments like IRS, CDS, XCCY basis swap and some options, etc.

Comment: Not everything you'd need to know by far, but good blog https://www.sifma.org/resources/news/the-fundamental-review-of-the-trading-book-frtb-an-introductory-guide/ worthwhile book https://www.amazon.com/dp/1782723242

Comment: Is this book up to date? The release is 2018 so wondering if it contains the latest changes in regulation?

Comment: Any 2018 book is definitely less than fully up to date.

Comment: Walking through [this tutorial](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/JEFAS-12-2021-0268/full/pdf) might help.